# Extract a part of string and join to the start

Tags: r, regex, string, list

I have a list

```
temp_list <- c("Temp01_T1", "Temp03_T1", "Temp04_T1", "Temp11_T6", 
"Temp121_T6", "Temp99_T8")
```

I want to change this list as follows

```
output_list <- c("T1_Temp01", "T1_Temp03", "T1_Temp04", "T6_Temp11", 
    "T6_Temp121", "T8_Temp99")
```

Any leads would be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Base R answer using `sub` -

```
sub('(\\w+)_(\\w+)', '\\2_\\1', temp_list)
#[1] "T1_Temp01"  "T1_Temp03"  "T1_Temp04"  "T6_Temp11"  "T6_Temp121" "T8_Temp99"
```

You can capture the data in two capture groups, one before underscore and another one after the underscore and reverse them using backreference.

Answer (score 3):

This should work.

`sub("(.*)(_)(.*)", "\\3\\2\\1", temp_list)`

You capture the three groups, one before the underscore, one is the underscore and one after and then you rearrange the order in the replacement expression.

Answer (score 2):

python approach: splitting on '_', reversing order with -1 step index slicing, and joining with '_':

```
['_'.join(i.split('_')[::-1]) for i in temp_list]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str_split()` from `stringr` and then use `sapply()` to paste it in the order you want if it is always seperated by a `_`

```
x <- stringr::str_split(temp_list, "_")
sapply(x, function(x){paste(x[[2]],x[[1]],sep = "_")})
```

Comment: Why not use base `strsplit`? And alternatively `paste(rev(x), collapse="_")`.

Comment: good ideas! honestly I am new to understanding string manipulation and still not aware of all the capabilities of regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

A trick with `paste` + `read.table`

```
> do.call(paste, c(rev(read.table(text = temp_list, sep = "_")), sep = "_"))
[1] "T1_Temp01"  "T1_Temp03"  "T1_Temp04"  "T6_Temp11"  "T6_Temp121"
[6] "T8_Temp99"
```